# How to get the FTP path starting from the root of the user directory?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the WordPress method `$wp_filesystem->put_contents()` to write a file to the server. When I use an absolute path like the following no file will be put to that location:

```
/www/htdocs/w423fe4/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/file.zip
```

However when I change the path to start only after the user name (w423fe4) the file is indeed put to the server. So my question is is there any way to programmatically get the server path starting from the root of the user account in PHP? So basically what I like to get in the above case is this:

```
/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/file.zip
```

Or is this not possible because every server somehow has a different structure?

Comment: `$_SERVER`  superglobal has all that information.

Comment: I don't see how the `$_SERVER` superglobal would give me only the path starting from the current user's home directory or am I missing something?

Comment: `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` = your server path to web root, add to it as you need to get your folder, or use `__DIR__` to define a global variable in the folder you want. if you look up server there is also `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` which can also be used to get the current folder location, i.e. you can combine the returned strings to build your path. If its a plugin for example you can define your `$path` variable in the main file and build to it from there.

Comment: I still don't understand how I can find out where the user directory starts. On some servers there is `$_SERVER["home"]` however not on Windows servers. It seems to be not possible to determine the user`s home directory properly no matter the server type and settings.

Comment: i'm guessing you want to place folders/files outside the wp folder either for offline or outside wp htaccess? You cannot guess as to the structure, there are loads of diff structures, you are prob on shared hosting vms you will just have the folder assigned as the webroot for the domain etc. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

It would be "~/" at the beginning. "~" is a shortcut for the current user's home directory

Comment: That's awesome, I didn't know that. But now how could I use that to make sure the path is always correct for any user. So with `~/` I can set the path to the current user's home directory but then from there I don't know where the WordPress install actually lies. I would somehow need to combine the `~/` with the absolute path which the `$_SERVER` superglobal returns.